# Build a database using Google Cloud platform and update tableau dashboard automatically

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, tableau-api

I am not a programmer / cloud expert, but I want to give it a try and see what I can build myself.
Ultimately, I want to build an automated Tableau dashboard that using refreshed API data.

Where should I start building the whole thing?

Here are some questions that I am seeking the answer for:

1. How do I upload API data to Google Cloud Storage? How can I keep the data refresh? What kind of skills(or programming) do I need for this?
2. I want to use BigQuery for analytics purpose, so do I need to build a database for my API data, or using Google Cloud Storage alone would do the task?
3. Tableau supports BigQuery, but how can I get refreshed data without loading? (Like I will get the latest number everytime I open the Tableau file)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I upload API data to Google Cloud Storage? How can I keep the data refresh? What kind of skills(or programming) do I need for this?

You can upload data to Google Cloud Storage without programming:

- you can drag-and-drop files via [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com)
- you can use the [`gsutil`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) command-line tool to automate uploads

> I want to use BigQuery for analytics purpose, so do I need to build a database for my API data, or using Google Cloud Storage alone would do the task?

You can [load data from Google Cloud Storage to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage).

> Tableau supports BigQuery, but how can I get refreshed data without loading? (Like I will get the latest number everytime I open the Tableau file)

You can also [query data in Google Cloud Storage directly from BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage) without loading it into BigQuery first, but you'll have to define an external data source, and it's unclear whether that will address your use case.

Regarding always getting the latest data: Tableau will re-query BigQuery, which will re-issue the query on its data sources, whether it's in BigQuery storage or external storage.

Comment: Thanks for great advice, finally managed to upload object to storage using gsutil in Python environment. Just wondering if we can setup scheduled uploads in python?

Comment: To schedule tasks to execute regularly on your local Linux or macOS box, you can use [`crontab`](http://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/29/schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-crontab/).